# Varnish and Cloudflare inner page setting for First Time Byte

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, varnish, cloud

I optimized my site and according to webpage test its very good. However if i check homepage im getting A mark for First Byte Time if i check an inner page than its F.

Home:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150209_3Q_4NX/

Inner:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150209_ZP_4PD/1/performance_optimization/#first_byte_time

When i was working on the home page and got the A result from F i didnt make change on a specified file but i adjusted CSS,JS Merge,Complier. Is it possible that these configuration only applied to home page that i should change or how can i get this result.

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that it's the hosting provider's fault.
I use cloud server with 2gb ram and 2cpu

Answer (score 0):

The result with an A rating looks like it got served cached HTML (Varnish or FPC most likely), the second one didn't.  I am seeing similar render times for both pages in firebug and I think if you run another test on the homepage you will get a similar result to the 'inner' page.